# Finding curve using arc length

Tags: calculus

A rabbit begins at the origin and runs up the − with speed . At the same time, a dog runs at speed  from the point $(,0)$ in pursuit of the rabbit. What is the path of the dog?
You may assume the arc length of a curve is given by $$L = \int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dL}{dx}\right)^2}\ dx $$

So I know that $\frac {dy}{dt} =a$ and $\frac {dx}{dt}=\sqrt{b^2-a^2}$ .

I am thinking to use chain rule $\frac{dL}{dy}\cdot \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$ but I don't know what $\frac{dL}{dy}$ would be. I am stuck here.

Comment: Duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852128/limiting-distance-of-a-chase-of-two-points, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249874/does-tom-catch-jerry

Comment: Please also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome

Comment: No it does not. My question specifies the use of arc length as the solution. I had also found those posts but they use different methods which I have not learnt.

Comment: The "deos tom catch jerry" one is the closest to arc length. I'll look into it

Comment: Is my way salvageble? I want to find $dL/dy$

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Math Lover, the Wikipaedia gives full details of the pursuit curve.. in this case aka radiodrome... so equations are not repeated.

With respect to arc lengths the paths are described by hyperbolic functions given there. We have

$$ s_d= V_d t, s_h= V_h t $$

so that arc lengths can be used instead of times.

If $V_d>V_h,\text{the dog catches hare};$

If $V_d<V_h,\text{ hare escapes};$

If $V_d=V_h$,the initial distance between them is always maintained constant along a path which is the *Tractrix of constant tangent length = c,* the dog reaches hare on y-axis asymptotically...means never.